# About Paypal Payment

Tags: php, paypal, payment

Hi dear stackoverflow users,

I wanna make active the paypal payment system. It's been so long to make active the paypal payment system to any website.

I've done trials from sandbox.paypal.com. Codes are as here

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">     
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="business@kayar.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">        
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="<?=$productName?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">        
    <input type='hidden' name='cancel_return' value='http://www.temafoni.com/flydesign/paypal/cancel.php'>
    <input type='hidden' name='return' value='http://www.temafoni.com/flydesign/paypal/success.php'>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger-outline btn-block">Buy Now</button>
</form>
```

I completed trials successfully, What should I do after this step?

Thanks for helping!

Comment: You should change the PayPal url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're ready to go live then you just need to remove "sandbox" from the URL and update the business email address with the live account address.

Comment: thank you so much, It seems like that paypal payment system didn't change :)